# Facebook SDK for Unity: Login doesn't let user specify a urlSchemeSuffix

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

With the previous plugin, we were able to specify a url scheme suffix, so when the OS switches back from FB to Unity, it will launch the correct app (in case you have 2 apps sharing fb id).

We have a free and paid version of an app, and we append 'free' on the app schema, but now without being able to specify that, the free customers are essentially broken, and they of course make up the vast number of users :(

Any chance we could get urlSchemaSuffix parameter added to the login method?

Comment: We will add support for this in an upcoming version.

Comment: Awesome! Really pleased with your guys' responsiveness on these issues!